# lambda in list comprehension error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing the following:

```
ll = [-8, -4, 0, 4, 8]
[lambda x: x**2 for x in ll]
```

and getting following error:

```
[<function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>]
```

What could be the problem? I know desired result can be achieved by below code but I want to understand why lambda is not working in list comprehension?

```
[x**2 for x in ll]
```

Comment: That's not an error. You get 5 lambda expressions in a list. What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the square of numbers in your list, you don't need the *lambda expression*. You should just do:

```
>>> [x**2 for x in ll]
[64, 16, 0, 16, 64]
```

In your usage, it is not an error. You are seeing the reference to lambda functions in your list (because you are not calling the function). In order to make it work, you may do:

```
>>> ll = [-8, -4, 0, 4, 8]
>>> f = lambda x: x**2
>>> [f(x) for x in ll]
[64, 16, 0, 16, 64]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
>>> [(lambda x: x**2)(x) for x in ll]
[64, 16, 0, 16, 64]
```

*Note:* Lambda is not at all needed here

Answer (score 3):

lambda returns a function, it does not evaluate the function, you may want:

```
ll = [-8, -4, 0, 4, 8]
[x**2 for x in ll]
```

or

```
ll = [-8, -4, 0, 4, 8]
f = lambda x: x**2
[f(x) for x in ll]
```

and it is equal to:

```
ll = [-8, -4, 0, 4, 8]
def f(x):
   return x**2
[f(x) for x in ll]
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel and @Moinuddin for the reply. So what I understood now is that [lambda x: x**2 for x in ll] will return a list containing references to 5 functions.
I was expecting that it will return one function object and that function will be applied to the elements of the list "ll".

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to invoke the `lambda`.  Here's a way to do it in line:

```
ll = [-8, -4, 0, 4, 8]
print([(lambda x: x**2)(x) for x in ll])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't make clear what you expected instead, but I'm suggesting this:

```
ll = [-8, -4, 0, 4, 8]
f = lambda x: x**2
print([f(x) for x in ll])
```